# Reading entire response through socket with good performance

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-core

I have written some code to get a webpage through a proxy using sockets.  In essence, it works but reading the response has some strange behavior that is really tripping me up.

When I go to read the response after sending the `GET` command it is 0 bytes.  It takes a few ticks before there is data to read.  I don't want to hard code a delay in here as I am trying to write performant reliable code so I have coded a while loop that keeps reading the response until it more than 0.

This works for the first chunk but trying to read subsequent chunks is a problem.  If i instantly try to read the response it will be 0 bytes so I need to check the subsequent reads also if they are greater than 0.

So to read the whole response I tried to check if the response is equal to the size of the buffer.  If it is equal to the size of the buffer then I carry on and try to read another chunk.  This has a few issues also.  Sometimes the response will read less than the size of the buffer but there is still more to come, i guess I am reading it faster than they are sending it because if I add a `Thread.Sleep()` then the buffer will always be full but I don't think it is good practice to hardcode this because I don't know how fast they will be sending.  This code will be used for multiple things and will be running on hundreds of threads so performance is everything.

Also if the last chunk just happens to be the size of my buffer then I think the loop will lock,  This whole approach I have taken is horrible but I can't see how I should be reading it.  I have seen the asynchronous examples but I think that will add to the overall complexity of my code as I just have 1 set process which I will run in many threads.

How do I efficiently read the response when I can't guarantee the next chunk will have data or be full even if there is more data to come?

Sorry for long text but I wanted to explain my thinking.  Here is my code:

```
    // Data buffer for incoming data.  
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    // Connect to a remote device.  
    try
    {
        var proxyIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("123.123.123.123"); //omitted

        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(proxyIpAddress, 60099);

        // Create a TCP/IP  socket.  
        Socket sender = new Socket(proxyIpAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.  
        try
        {
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            sender.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"CONNECT google.com:80 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"));

            int bytesRec = 0;

            while (bytesRec == 0)
            {
                // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
            }

            //clear buffer
            bytes = new byte[1024];
            bytesRec = 0;

            sender.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"));

            //wait for response
            while (bytesRec == 0) //if i dont add this it returns before it actually gets data
            {
                // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
            }

            if(bytes.Length == bytesRec)  //full buffer so likely more but maybe not if final packet exactly 1024?
            {
                while (bytes.Length == bytesRec) //again if i miss this it returns too early
                {
                    int subsequentBytes = 0;
                    while(subsequentBytes == 0) //this can get stuck if last packet exactly size of buffer i think
                    {
                        subsequentBytes = sender.Receive(bytes);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}",
                            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, subsequentBytes));

                        //this doesn't work.  even when there are subsequent bytes sometimes it reads less
                        //than the size of the buffer so it exits prematurely.  If I add a Thread.Sleep() here
                        // then it works but I don't want to hardcode the delay. How do I read this buffer properly? 
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        if (subsequentBytes > 0) bytesRec = subsequentBytes; 
                    }
                }
            }
            // Release the socket.  
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
```

I understand this is difficult to follow and a lot of writing so if anyone perseveres with this they have my gratitude as the only option I can see is hardcoded pauses which will hurt performance and may still have issues.

**EDIT**

I have done some experiementing with different servers.  If I ping the server then set a `Thread.Sleep(pingValue)` it works fine but if i set the sleep to lower than ping i get same issue.

Is there some good way with the .net libraries to account for this latency so I am not under/overestimating?

Comment: I hope you can Identify start and end of the packet some way. If yes please refer to http://www.rickykumar.com/ .

Comment: The problem you are facing is very common when dealing with socket, serial port communication.

Comment: Are you sure about what you're reporting? You *should not* be receiving zero bytes from `Receive`, except when the other side closes its socket. The `Receive` should block until there is some data available from the peer. If you had a socket timeout set, and that expired before any data arrived, an exception should be thrown -- i.e. you still shouldn't receive a return value of zero.

Comment: Yes, If I do not account for network latency of the response it receives zero bytes.  I have found servers with high latency to test this on.  To make the code work I am timing how long first request takes then adding error margin and pausing execution for this much time each time before i read response.  I am unhappy with this approach but I cannot see any other way to handle it

Comment: I just looked into http protocol and it is addressed. There is a content-length header i can use apparently to know how much to read